# Implementing a protocol version in my code

Tags: version

I am writing an application which will be used for event sending. As it stands right now the application is done, however in the future there will be additions to the application. Those additions will be new versions. My question is how to actually implement those version. Sure I can go for "if version == xx" but doing that in every method, in constructors, just does not seem as the exact solution, that's why I am asking for help from people with experience in implementing those versions. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [protocol-buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)? You can extend your protocol with great backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing can be handled with implementing [forward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility). Unfortunately, I cannot give you any practical advice without knowing anything about your protocol. There are some general steps you could follow, though:

- Only change the protocol if you really have to.
- Ensure you do not break backward compatibility.
- Force the user to update the application when update the protocol. This ensures there is only one valid version at a time.
- If you have to support multiple versions of the protocol you could implement some kind of converter. But this might not work in every case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Points:
1) Yes it will only be changed if I have to.
2) Backward compatibility will NEVER be broken.
3) Forcing the user to update their application is impossible unfortunately.
4) I will look into the converters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll deal the problem with Interfaces and Factory pattern.

For example:

- Create an Interface with all the methods.
- Create differents implementations for each version.
- Use Factory to get the proper implementation